# Can this script wait for an external process to complete?

Tags: bash, shell, wait

I have written this shell script as wrapper to a JAR file. The script launches the JAR without problem but completes without waiting for the JAR to finish its job.

```
#!/bin/bash

export WORK=/opt/conversion
export LOG=$WORK
export XMAIL=me@email.com
export JAVA_BASE=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_06
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_06/bin
export JAR=$WORK/conversion.jar
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_BASE/lib/tools.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$WORK/lib/ojdbc14.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAR

$JAVA_HOME/java -Xms256M -Xmx512M -classpath $CLASSPATH com.myapp.cam.conversion >>$WORK/job.out 2>&1 &

echo $! > $WORK/job.pid
mail -s "Conversion" $XMAIL < $WORK/user_message
exit 0
```

Is there a way to have the script wait on my JAR file to complete?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `&` at the end of the command:

```
$JAVA_HOME/java -Xms256M -Xmx512M -classpath $CLASSPATH com.myapp.cam.conversion >>$WORK/job.out 2>&1 &
```

which makes it run in background.

Remove the `&` to wait for the `java` process to complete before you proceed in the script.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, remove the `&` and bash will wait till the command finishes. If you insist on running your process in the background, here is what you could do:

```
pid=`pidof java`

if [ "$pid" ]; then
    while kill -0 "$pid"; do
        sleep 1
    done
fi
```

The `kill` command is normally used to send signals to a particular process, but by using `0` as a signal you are only checking whether a process with such a pid exists without sending a signal.

Comment: Which is the best practice? Wait until the command finishes or running my process in the background?

Comment: Normally you should wait, but there are cases where an external script needs to know whether a process is running, and this is a viable solution.

Comment: `$PID=` is not a valid assignment; presumably you just mean `PID=`. (But don't use all-caps names for your own variables; they're [reserved for variables with meaning to the OS or shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)).

Comment: Also, `while kill -0 "$PID"; do` is more correct here -- if `kill -0` doesn't emit anything on stdout (and it typically doesn't), then you're otherwise running `while [ ]; do` after expansion -- so your loop would exit immediately on the first invocation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: corrected the answer as per your remarks.

Comment: Looks good as amended. (Incidentally, with a new enough bash to have `wait -n` you can sleep until at least one subprocess exits instead of needing to continually poll, but that's just a potential enhancement, as opposed to a bug).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it in the background, add a `wait` command at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the conversion Java application in the background. Or, run `ps` repeatedly until you don't see the pid. This will allow you to do stuff while waiting.